# Why is my "port" button on the toolbar greyed out?

Tags: teensy

I am trying to program a Teensy 3.2 to act as a lightsaber controller. My code works perfectly but I can't select a port. How should I fix this problem?

Here is my code:

```
/* Presented without warranty, guarantee and support.
    By Bob Clagett - I Like To Make Stuff

   This is the code to accompany the lightsaber project at http://www.iliketomakestuff.com/make-lightsaber/
   Expected hardware is listed in post (Teensy 3.2, Prop Shield, DotStar LEDs)

   This is functional v1 of this code.  Lots more I want to add to it including crash detection/sounds.
   This code is dirty, bulky, poorly documented and ugly but I finally got it all functional.
   Cleanup to come later in v2.
*/



#include <SerialFlash.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

// GUItool: begin automatically generated code

// GUItool: end automatically generated code

#include <Adafruit_DotStar.h>
#include <NXPMotionSense.h>

NXPMotionSense imu;
NXPSensorFusion filter;

int motionThreshold = 2;

float lastPitch = 0, lastRoll = 0, lastHeading = 0;

int buttonState = HIGH;
int bladeState = 0; //0 off, 1, fading up, 2 on, 3 fading down
int fadeStep = 0;
int fadeStepSize = 6;
int selectedColor = 0;
int lastSelectedColor = 0;
bool isAnimating = 0;
bool bladeOn = 0;
long lastDebounceTime = 0;  // the last time the output pin was toggled
long debounceDelay = 50;
int lastButtonState = HIGH;
int pendingPress = 0;

//BC = Blade Color
int BCbuttonState = HIGH;
long BClastDebounceTime = 0;  // the last time the output pin was toggled
long BCdebounceDelay = 50;
int BClastButtonState = HIGH;
int BCpendingPress = 0;
int pendingColorPress = 0;

#define COLOR_BUTTON_PIN 1
#define POWER_BUTTON_PIN 0
#define COLOR_ORDER BGR
#define CHIPSET     APA102
#define NUMPIXELS    252

#define BRIGHTNESS  100
#define FRAMES_PER_SECOND 70

#define PROP_AMP_ENABLE 5
#define FLASH_CHIP_SELECT 6
#define LED_BUFFER_SELECT 7

#define VOLUME_POT 15

#define LED_PIN    7
Adafruit_DotStar strip = Adafruit_DotStar(
                           NUMPIXELS, DOTSTAR_BRG);

int outputValue = 0;
int presetColors[] = {0x0000FF, 0x00FF00, 0xFF0000, 0xFFFFFF};
int totalPresetColors = (sizeof(presetColors) / sizeof(int));
int selectedColorIndex = 0;

int swingSounds = 4;
int lastSwingSound = swingSounds;

int clashSounds = 0;
void setup() {
  delay(500); // sanity delay
  imu.begin();
  filter.begin(100);
#if defined(__AVR_ATtiny85__) && (F_CPU == 16000000L)
  clock_prescale_set(clock_div_1); // Enable 16 MHz on Trinket
#endif

  strip.begin(); // Initialize pins for output
  strip.show();  // Turn all LEDs off ASAP

  pinMode(POWER_BUTTON_PIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(COLOR_BUTTON_PIN, INPUT);
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(POWER_BUTTON_PIN, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(COLOR_BUTTON_PIN, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);

  Serial.begin(9600);
  // wait up to 3 seconds for the Serial device to become available
  long unsigned debug_start = millis ();
  while (!Serial && ((millis () - debug_start) <= 3000))
    ;

  Serial.println ("Start prop shield RAW player");
  SPI.begin();
  // Enable the amplifier on the prop shield
  pinMode(PROP_AMP_ENABLE, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(PROP_AMP_ENABLE, HIGH);
  pinMode(LED_BUFFER_SELECT, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUFFER_SELECT, HIGH);

  // Audio connections require memory to work.  For more
  // detailed information, see the MemoryAndCpuUsage example


  // Set initial volume


  // Start SerialFlash
  if (!SerialFlash.begin(FLASH_CHIP_SELECT)) {
    while (1)
    {
      Serial.println ("Cannot access SPI Flash chip");
      delay (3000);
    }
  }

}

void powerUpBlade() {

  isAnimating = 1;
  bladeState = 1;
  Serial.println("Turn on blade");
  bladeOn = 1;

}

void powerDownBlade() {
  //animate DOWN

  bladeState = 3;
  fadeStep = NUMPIXELS;
  isAnimating = 1;
  Serial.println("Turn off blade");

  bladeOn = 0;
}

void bladeIsOn() {


}
//nothing needed here unless adding animation


void bladeIsAnimatingUp() {
  //Serial.println("bladeIsAnimatingUp");
  int midpoint = NUMPIXELS / 2;
  int newSection = fadeStep + fadeStepSize;
  for ( int j = fadeStep; j < newSection; j++) {
    strip.setPixelColor(j, selectedColor);
    strip.setPixelColor(NUMPIXELS - j, selectedColor);
  }
  Serial.println(newSection);
  fadeStep = newSection;

  if (fadeStep >= midpoint + fadeStepSize) {

    fadeStep = NUMPIXELS;
    isAnimating = 0;
    bladeState = 2;
    //      delay(200);
    Serial.println("blade up complete");

  }
}

void bladeIsAnimatingDown() {
  //Serial.println("bladeIsAnimatingDown");
  int midpoint = NUMPIXELS / 2;
  int newSection = fadeStep - fadeStepSize;
  for ( int j = fadeStep; j > newSection; j--) {

    strip.setPixelColor(j - midpoint, 0x000000);

    strip.setPixelColor(midpoint + NUMPIXELS - j, 0x000000);
  }
  //Serial.println(fadeStep);
  fadeStep = newSection;

  if (fadeStep <= midpoint - fadeStepSize) {
    fadeStep = 0;
    isAnimating = 0;
    bladeState = 0;
  }
}

void detectMotion() {
  float ax, ay, az;
  float gx, gy, gz;
  float mx, my, mz;
  float roll, pitch, heading;

  if (imu.available()) {
    // Read the motion sensors
    imu.readMotionSensor(ax, ay, az, gx, gy, gz, mx, my, mz);

    // Update the SensorFusion filter
    filter.update(gx, gy, gz, ax, ay, az, mx, my, mz);

    // print the heading, pitch and roll
    roll = filter.getRoll();
    pitch = filter.getPitch();
    heading = filter.getYaw();

    // does it need a time threshold too?

    float headingDiff = abs(lastHeading - heading);
    float pitchDiff = abs(lastPitch - pitch);
    if (lastHeading != 0) {
      if (pitchDiff > motionThreshold || headingDiff > motionThreshold) {
        //cyle through swing sounds
        lastSwingSound++;
        if (lastSwingSound > swingSounds) {
          lastSwingSound = 1;
        }
        String swingFile = "saberswingX.raw";

        char charBuf[50];
        swingFile.toCharArray(charBuf, 50);
        triggerSwing(charBuf);  // needs sequence to iterate through
      }
    }
    lastHeading = heading;
    lastPitch = pitch;
  }

}
void loop() {
  // Add entropy to random number generator; we use a lot of it.
  // random16_add_entropy( random() );

  //handle color selector button
  int BCreading = digitalRead(COLOR_BUTTON_PIN);

  if (BCreading != BClastButtonState) {
    // reset the debouncing timer
    BClastDebounceTime = millis();
  }

  if ((millis() - BClastDebounceTime) > BCdebounceDelay) {
    if (BCreading != BCbuttonState) {
      BCbuttonState = BCreading;

      if (BCbuttonState == HIGH) {
        nextColor();
      }
    }
  }
  BClastButtonState = BCreading;

  selectedColor = presetColors[selectedColorIndex];
  if (selectedColor != lastSelectedColor && bladeState != 0) {
    Serial.print("COLOR CHANGE");
    Serial.println(selectedColorIndex);
    for ( int j = 0; j < NUMPIXELS; j++) {
      strip.setPixelColor(j, selectedColor);
    }
  }
  lastSelectedColor = selectedColor;

  //handle blade on/off

  int reading = digitalRead(POWER_BUTTON_PIN);
  //debounce
  if (reading != lastButtonState) {
    // reset the debouncing timer
    lastDebounceTime = millis();
  }

  if ((millis() - lastDebounceTime) > debounceDelay) {
    if (reading != buttonState) {
      buttonState = reading;
    }
  }
  lastButtonState = reading;

  if ( pendingPress == 1 && buttonState != LOW) {
    buttonState = HIGH;
    pendingPress = 0;
    Serial.print("execute pending blade press");

    if (bladeOn) {
      powerDownBlade();
    } else {
      powerUpBlade();
    }
  }

  if (buttonState == LOW && !isAnimating) {
    Serial.println("BLADE BUTTON IS PRESSED");
    pendingPress = 1;
  }
  switch (bladeState) {
    case 0:
      //blade is off
      break;
    case 1:
      //blade is animating up
      bladeIsAnimatingUp();
      break;
    case 2:
      //blade is on
      bladeIsOn();
      break;
    case 3:
      //blade is animating down
      bladeIsAnimatingDown();
      break;
  }
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(10000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);  // enable access to LEDs
  strip.show();                     // Refresh strip
  digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
  SPI.endTransaction();   // allow other libs to use SPI again

  delay(10);

  if (bladeState == 2) {
    detectMotion();
  }

}
void nextColor() {
  selectedColorIndex++;
  if (selectedColorIndex >= totalPresetColors) {
    selectedColorIndex = 0;
  }
}
void triggerSound(const char *filename) {

}
void triggerSwing(const char *filename) {


}



void startHum() {
  //Serial.println("startHum");



}
```

Comment: what port are you talking about? ... how is it related to your sketch?

Comment: please format your code to make it readable

Comment: So your problem is with the Arduino IDE or with the detection of the teensy board on your PC? Which of OS and which IDE version do you use?

Comment: From what I understand TeensyDuino modifies your Arduino IDE installation to make it work with the Teensy. Once that is done it is no longer the Arduino IDE. It doesn't use the standard board manager installation system, but direct modification of the IDE itself. I am not aware of a "port" button in the Arduino IDE (there is a port menu entry though, which only appears if you have a serial port available). The Teensy doesn't use serial for uploading code. You shouldn't need a port for that.

Comment: The error message says “you do not have a port selected”. I am talking about the port button in the too bar.

Comment: I mean the tool bar

Comment: There *is* no port button in the toolbar of the Arduino IDE. There is "Verify", "Upload", "New", "Open", "Save", and on the far end "Serial Monitor".

Comment: Did you fix the problem? I am Working with the same code, but something is stocking with
Colors. I am working with NeoPihel and WS2812.